# Plone 5.0.3 file uploads fails with msg "The file transfer failed"

Tags: plone

Plone 5 features file uploads from the folder contents view. When I try to upload files it fails with "The file transfer failed" below the filename (without mentioning the cause). The Plone 5.0.3 site is brand new.
I tried with several file types and different users (also admin). 
In site settings (after clearing the "Ignored exception types") I do see an error.

The user name is peculiar ("Anonymous User ()"), since I am definitely logged in or I wouldn't be able to add any content. I *can* upload files via the normal add item menu item.

```
<pre>
Time
Apr 02, 2016 11:07 PM
User Name
Anonymous User ()
Request URL
http://localhost:8000/ultest/fileUpload
Exception Type
NotFound
Exception Value
http://localhost:8000/ultest/fileUpload
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 523, in traverse
Module ZPublisher.HTTPResponse, line 727, in debugError
NotFound: <h2>Site Error</h2> <p>An error was encountered while publishing this resource. </p> <p><strong>Debugging Notice</strong></p> Zope has encountered a problem publishing your object.<p> Cannot locate object at: http://localhost:8000/ultest/fileUpload</p> <hr noshade="noshade"/> <p>Troubleshooting Suggestions</p> <ul> <li>The URL may be incorrect.</li> <li>The parameters passed to this resource may be incorrect.</li> <li>A resource that this resource relies on may be encountering an error.</li> </ul> <p>For more detailed information about the error, please refer to the error log. </p> <p>If the error persists please contact the site maintainer. Thank you for your patience. </p>
</pre>
```

Comment: I tested the feature on an empty Plone 5.0.3 site and it works. You have probably some additional layer in the middle? A ngnix server, apache or varnish?

Comment: You should inspect your network calls with your web browser debugger, so you can have a look to the AJAX request to /fileUpload.

Comment: Clearing ignored exception types will cause exceptions to be recorded that may not be meaningful. This error message is likely a consequence of the upload failure and not useful in determining the cause.

Comment: I think I pinned down the problem. I'd forgotten that I had installed plone.restapi. It turns out it breaks the file upload functionality. Didn't see that one coming. Filed a [bug report](https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi/issues/74).